# MERGE with multiple UPDATE statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we achieve below scenario using single MERGE statement:

source table - table1
destination table- table2

when table1.id in table2.id
  then update table1 SET phone_number=123456

when table1.id not in table2.id 
  then update table1 SET phone_number=555555

Note:- i am able to achieve the result using below query .

```
MERGE INTO table1 tbl1
USING table2 tbl2 
ON (tbl1.id = tbl2.id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET tbl1.phone_number=123456;

update table1 set phone_number = 555555 where id not in (select id from table2);
```

Is there any way to achieve it by using only MERGE Statement ?

Comment: you can try when not matched ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar `WHEN NOT MATCHED` is for when the value is in `table2` but not in `table1`. The OP appears to want the equivalent of the SQL Server syntax `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY [SOURCE|TARGET]` (which does not exist in Oracle) so that they can update values in `table1` when there is no value in `table2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no rows are matched then you can not use `UPDATE` (in `WHEN NOT MATCHED`). as there are no rows matched then which data should be updated?

Normal merge statement must have following structure:

> ```
> MERGE <hint> INTO <table_name>
> USING <table_view_or_query>
> ON (<condition>)
> WHEN MATCHED THEN <update_clause>
> DELETE <where_clause>
> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN <insert_clause>
> [LOG ERRORS <log_errors_clause> <reject limit <integer | unlimited>];
> ```

When there is no match then there are no rows found by oracle into your `target` table which matches with `source` table using `ON` condition then how can it update the record? which record it will update?

`WHEN NOT MATCHED` is illustrated as following in [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#i2090698):

[image]

You can handle your scenario using **MERGE** as follows:

**-- Oracle data creation**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE table1 ( id number, phone_number number );
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL> INSERT INTO table1
>   2  SELECT 1, 111 from dual UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 2, 222 from dual UNION ALL
>   4  SELECT 3, 333 from dual UNION ALL
>   5  SELECT 4, 444 from dual;
>
> 4 rows created.
>
> SQL> drop table table2;
>
> Table dropped.
>
> SQL> CREATE TABLE table2 ( id number );
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL> INSERT INTO table2
>   2  SELECT 1 from dual UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 2 from dual;
>
> 2 rows created.
> ```

**-- Your merge statement**

> ```
> SQL> MERGE INTO TABLE1 TBL1
>   2  USING (
>   3           SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID AS T2ID
>   4           FROM TABLE1 T1
>   5               LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
>   6       )
>   7  TBL2 ON ( TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID )
>   8  WHEN MATCHED THEN
>   9  UPDATE SET TBL1.PHONE_NUMBER = NVL2(TBL2.T2ID, 123456, 555555);
>
> 4 rows merged.
> ```

**-- Result**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
>
>         ID PHONE_NUMBER
> ---------- ------------
>          1       123456
>          2       123456
>          3       555555
>          4       555555
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `UPDATE` statement:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id, phone_number ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
SET    phone_number = COALESCE(
                        (
                          SELECT 123456
                          FROM   table2 t2
                          WHERE  t1.id = t2.id
                        ),
                        555555
                      )
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1
```

> ```
> ID | PHONE_NUMBER
> -: | -----------:
>  1 |       123456
>  2 |       555555
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61a888bfeff765e6252a8c9e56a463a0)*

---

The syntax you are looking for in a `MERGE` statement exists in SQL Server but is **NOT** valid in Oracle:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING table2 t2
ON ( t1.id = t2.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET phone_number = 123456
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  UPDATE SET phone_number = 555555;
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=33e6a1e06ab2e2cbc3516dc9622594c3)